# Using and returning methods

Tags: java, methods, return

For step 1 and 2 I am trying to figure out what type of dog must be defined in the main method so that it can be any type of dog and what type of dog must the getDog method return so it can be any type of dog.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogsTest
{
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    final String YES = "y";

    String answer;
    _______________________________ my_dog;                          // Step 1

    do
    {
      // ------------------------------------------------------------
      // The compiler cannot know at compile time what type my_dog is
      // so it is determined at runtime every time the loop iterates
      // ------------------------------------------------------------
      my_dog = getDog();
      System.out.println(my_dog.getName() + " says " + my_dog.speak());

      System.out.print("Try again? ");
      answer = input.next();
    } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(YES));
  }

  public static _________________ getDog()                           // Step 2
  {
    int choice;
    ____________________ selected_dog;                               // Step 3
    String name,
           color;

    do
    {
      // ----------------------------------
      // A null reference indicates that an
      // invalid menu choice was entered
      // ----------------------------------
      selected_dog = null;
      System.out.print("Choose a Breed (1. Labrador  2. Yorkshire): ");
      choice = input.nextInt();

      switch (choice)
      {
        case 1:  System.out.print("Enter dog's name: ");
                 name = input.next();
                 System.out.print("Enter dog's color: ");
                 color = input.next();
                 selected_dog = __________________________________;  // Step 4
                 break;
        case 2:  System.out.print("Enter dog's name: ");
                 name = input.next();
                 selected_dog = __________________________________;  // Step 5
                 break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                 break;
      }
    } while (selected_dog == null);
    return __________________;                                       // Step 6
  }
}
```

Dog class

```
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Dog superclass:
//
//   A class that holds a dog's name and can make it speak
// -------------------------------------------------------
public class Dog
{
  protected String name;

  public Dog(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String speak()
  {
    return "Woof";
  }
}
```

Labrador class

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Labrador subclass:
//
//   A class derived from Dog that holds information about
//   a labrador retriever, overrides the Dog speak method and
//   includes information about average weight for this breed
// ----------------------------------------------------------
public class Labrador extends Dog
{
  private String color;
  private static int breed_weight = 75;

  public Labrador(String name, String color)
  {
    this.color = color;
  }

  // =========================================
  // Big bark -- overrides speak method in Dog
  // =========================================
  public String speak()
  {
    return "WOOF";
  }

  public static int avgBreedWeight()
  {
    return breed_weight;
  }
}
```

Yorkshire class

```
// -------------------------------------------------------
// Yorkshire subclass:
//
//   A class derived from Dog that holds information about
//   a Yorkshire terrier and overrides Dog speak method
// -------------------------------------------------------
public class Yorkshire extends Dog
{

  public Yorkshire(String name)
  {
    super(name);
  }

  // ===========================================
  // Small bark -- overrides speak method in Dog
  // ===========================================
  public String speak()
  {
    return "woof";
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the types of `Dog`s available to use. But it will be the one highest in the hierarchy.

Comment: As far as i know there is only Labrador and Yorkshire

Comment: I'm guessing the Labrador and Yorskhire classes extend something. That will be the class you want to use.

Comment: They do not. That is all the available code, this is a college cis 201 assignment with very unclear instructions

Comment: So there are no other classes provides to you at all? What type is selected_dog supposed to be? Something is missing here. Edit: there has to be other classes provided to you, as `my_dog.speak()` is doing a method call to another class not here.

Comment: I uploaded all other classes but i dont believe they provide any useful information

Comment: I literally said `I'm guessing the Labrador and Yorskhire classes extend something.` Look at `public class Yorkshire extends Dog`...

Answer (score 0):

Now that you provided the additional classes, I can tell you that the correct type is simply just `Dog`.

So `public static Dog getDog()`, and use `Dog` everywhere else that's requiring a type.